# Recursive function and exception handling

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I am building a floating point calculator and I'm stuck. The fp calculator has prompt shape, so my problem is that where I handle the exceptions I leave the recursive function that keeps the prompt showing up and ends the execution:

```
let initialDictionary = ref EmptyDictionary;;

let launcher () = 
   print_string ("Welcome");
   let rec aux dic =
        try 
           print_string ("->");
           aux ( execute dic (s token (Lexing.from_string (read_line () ))));
         with
             End_of_exec -> print_endline ("closing")
             Var_not_assigned s -> printf "var %s not assigned" s
             in aux !initialDictionary;;
```

Where:

```
val exec : dictionary -> Instruction -> dictionary;
type dictionary = (string,float)list
```

The point here is that as lists are immutable on ocaml, the only way I have to keep my dictionary stacking variables with its value is applying recursion taking the value dictionary from exec return.

So any ideas on how not to leave the "prompt like" execution while showing exceptions?

Comment: Did you consider: `let dictionary = Hashtbl.create 31;;` ?

Comment: Its not an option, I have to do it with just a (string * float) list

Answer (score 1):

A [read eval print loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interpreter has all these different phases which must be handled separately, and I think your implementation tried to do too much in a single step. Just breaking down the second part of your function will help untangle the different error handlers:

```
let launcher () =
    let rec prompt dic =
        print_string "->";
        parse dic
    and parse dic =
        let res =
            try
                s token (Lexing.from_string @@ read_line ())
            with End_of_exec -> (print_encline "closing"; raise End_of_exec)
        in evalloop dic res
    and evalloop dic rep =
        let dic =
            try execute dic rep
            with Var_not_assigned s -> (printf "var %s not assigned\n" s; dic)
        in prompt dic
    in prompt !InitialDictionary;;
```

Since each sub function will either [tail call](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) the next one or fail with an exception, the overall code should be tail recursive and optimised to a loop.

The good thing about this is that now you get a better picture of what is going on, and it makes it easier to change an individual step of the loop without touching the rest.

By the way, recall that `read_line` may trigger an `End_of_file` exception as well, but it should be trivial now to handle it now (left as an exercise).

Answer (score 1):

Ok a friend of mine gave me a solution and thinking about it I cant figure out a more elegant way.

```
Let exec () =
   Let _= print_string "->" in
   ( try 
       Let inst = s token (Lexing.from_string (read_line())) in
      Try
        Let r = exec_instruction !initialDictionary inst in
        initialDictionary := r
      With
        | Var_not_assigned s -> printf "var %s not assigned. \n" s
        | Com_not_implemented s -> printf " command %s not implemented. \n" s
        | Function_not_implemented s -> printf " function %s not implemented. \n" s
   With
      | lexic_error -> print_endline "lexic error"
      | Parsing. Parse_error -> print_endline "sintax error"
```

);;

```
Let rec program cont =
If cont then
  Try
    Exec (); program true
  With
     | End_of_exec -> print_endline "closing"; program false;;

Program true
```

The only thing that bothers me its the `initialDictionary := r` assignment, because exec_instruction returns a dictionary so it can be done recursive but it works anyways, ill figure out something hah. 
Thank you for the help, if someone can see a brigther solution let me know.